# Django 5.1 models with fields using db_default throw on full_clean

Tags: django, django-models

Trying to implement Django 5's new `db_default` attribute for fields

Using the following field as an example:

```
editable = models.BooleanField(db_default=True)
```

Would expect that if `editable` not specified when creating a new instance, that ORM would not throw error but would still save instance, and that the value of `editable` would be set to `True` at the database level.

So executing the following to create a new object:

```
    product_obj = models.Product(
        id=id,
        name=name,
        is_active=is_active,
        inventory_type=inventory_type,
        leadtime=leadtime,
    )
    product_obj.full_clean()
    product_obj.save()
```

would be expected to succeed.

Instead `full_clean()` raises a `ValidationError`:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'editable': ['“<django.db.models.expressions.DatabaseDefault object at 0x151db1c70>” value must be either True or False.']}
```

and similar behavior occurs throughout my codebase for any field for which `db_default` is set (CharField with choices, IntegerField, etc)

Clearly I'm not understanding how `db_default` should be used.